# What transformation matrix can be used to move a triangle?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

[image: matrix transformation]

In image there is a triangle on a coordinate plane. Coordinates of a triangle are A(1, 2), B(1, 0) and C(3, 0)

If I represent all three coordinates in a 3x3 matrix, it will look like below:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Now I want to translate this triangle to new triangle whose coordinates will be A'(3,2), B'(3,0) and C'(5,0). And my new 3x3 matrix will look like below:

\begin{bmatrix}3&3&5\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}

I know this transformation can be done using matrix multiplication. But I don't know with what transformation matrix I should multiply? And How to write transformation Matrix for this type of transformation?

Thank you

Comment: What year/grade are you in? Do you know about homogeneous coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Take the original vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and "augment" by adding a new "z" coordinate with the value $1$:  $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\2&0&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$. Now you can write the $\begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ translation as $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and the effect of the translation on the vectors is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\2&0&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Note that after the matrix multiplication, the "z" coordinate remains $1$.

Comment: The "right" solution depends on the theory that the person who asked the question knows and can use. My bad if I misinterpreted the question, I just meant there is no linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ that allows you to do that, I edited my answer.

Comment: @Flutterblaxi so you were telling me this type of translation is not possible?

Comment: @zipperblock I just said it's not possible using **2x2** matrices.

Comment: @Flutterblaxi okay. Then it is possible above two dimension like 3x3, 4x4. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @zipperblock No, it's not about dimensions. It is always possible in $\Bbb R^n$ by using (n+1)x(n+1) matrix multiplication (homogeneous coordinates) but it is not possible to use nxn matrix multiplication (linear transformations), because translations are not linear. So for example in a plane (isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$) you can't use 2x2 matrices to compute translations and you'll need 3x3.

Comment: @Flutterblaxi Sorry for late reply. I think i need to study more to visualize why translations are not linear. But your answer will help me to look where I need to clear my concepts. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @zipperblock Don't worry. By the way the reason is very simple: linear transformations map 0 to 0 by definition and translations don't do that (unless the translation vector is 0.. In that case you just have Id, which is obviously linear).

Comment: @pinkfrog could you please give me some resources from where i could get clear picture on linear transformation? I already trying to get clear concepts from khan academy pre-calculus -> matrix -> matrix transformation. Thank you

Comment: @zipperblock Unfortunately I cannot, I'm Italian and *all my resources* were written by my professors. I'm sorry I can't help you with that

Comment: @pinkfrog no problem:) I can manage. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can only compute rotations and symmetries by using 2x2 matrix multiplication (i.e. linear transformations from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$), not translations. To obtain the second triangle you'll just need to translate by $\vec v=(2,0)^T$.

Comment: By augmenting the triangle vertex vectors you can write the translation as a matrix multiplication.

Comment: What do you mean by "augmenting the (...) vectors"?

Comment: see my answer below